# Complexity of Smoothed $\ell_0$ algorithm

Tags: compressed-sensing

I wanted to compute the complexity of a smoothed $\ell_0$ algorithm in BigO notation. The algorithm can be found [here](http://ee.sharif.edu/~SLzero/SL0_ICASSP08.pdf). Can anybody help me in this regard?

Comment: it would be helpful to expand the question so it's a little more self-contained. I.e try to specify the algorithm at a high level. Of course that in itself might have revealed the answer !

Answer (score 2):

There appear to be two user-introduced parameters $K,L$ in the algorithm you point to. Apart from that, the main task appears to be the computation of a pseudoinverse, and matrix multiplication. Without any further knowledge of the structure of the $n\times n$ matrix $A$, it would appear that the running time is $O(KL g(n))$, where $g(n)$ is your best estimate for computing the inverse and doing the multiplication.

Crudely, both of these can be bounded by $cn^3$, but there might be better answers based on your actual setting (if A is sparse, or if you use Strassen's matrix multiplication, and so on)

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Suresh to some extent. I think the complexity of SL0 is O(KLf(n))+ O(g(n)), where f(n) is complexity of multiplication two n by n matrices, and g(n) is complexity of computing the inverse matrix. For arbitrary matrices, f(n) = c.n^2 and g(n) = c.n^3
The mistake of Suresh is that algorithm just needs to calculate inverse matrix once (rather than KL times). The complexity is O(KLn^2) + O(n^3)

However, note that if you are trying to use the same system for representing more than one (let say T) samples, you do not need to do the inversion part every time. You do it once for all, and the complexity is O(TKLn^2)+O(n^3) (rather than O(TKLn^2) + O(Tn^3))